# Replacing $I$ with S.P.D. $B$ in ridge regression, is the norm still bounded by OLS?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, matrix-norms

Assuming invertible $(\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A})$, $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $\gamma\geq1$, the norm of the ridge regression solution $\mathbf{x}_{\gamma} = (\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A} + \gamma\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{y}$ can be shown to be upper bounded by the norm of the OLS solution $\mathbf{x}_0 = (\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{y}$, [as shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145531/regularized-least-squares-solution-norm-bounded-by-least-squares-solution-norm)
$$
\|\mathbf{x}_{\gamma}\| \leq \|\mathbf{x}_0 \|\;.
$$

I was wondering if a similar bound can be shown for the norm of
$$
\mathbf{x'}_{\gamma} = (\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A} + \gamma\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\;,
$$
for some symmetric, positive semi-definite (or positive definite) $\mathbf{B}$. Since $\mathbf{x'}_{\gamma}$ is a more general form of $\mathbf{x}_{\gamma}$, it seems intuitive to me that this should be possible. But for [a similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581690/inverse-of-sum-of-matrices-has-lower-norm-than-the-inverse-of-summands) that I posted a few days ago no such upper bound could be shown.

I'll post a supporting simulation experiment later today!

---

Edit: Alternatively, showing the following would also be sufficient for my purposes
$$
\|\mathbf{x}''_{\gamma}\| \leq \|\mathbf{x}''_{0} \|\;,\;\;\;\;\mathbf{x}''_{\gamma} = (\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A} + \gamma\mathbf{K}^{\top}\mathbf{K})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\;,
$$
where the rows of $\mathbf{K}\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$ are orthonormal, and $k\leq m$.

Comment: If $B$ is only positive semidefinite and its null space intersects with the null space of $A$, then $(A^{T}A+\gamma B)^{-1}$ won't exist.

Comment: Assume that $(\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A} + \gamma\mathbf{B})^{-1}$ exists for the purposes of this question.

But a detail I left out (if you feel it would be relevant), is that I am constructing $\mathbf{B}:=\mathbf{G}^{\top}\mathbf{G}$ where the rows of $\mathbf{G}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ lie in the null space of the ground-truth parameters $\mathbf{x}^{\ast}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. Also, $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is full rank ($n > m$).

Comment: @johndoe I suspect that your desired result won't hold. However, I think that in the case of an invertible $B$, there is an alternative norm of the form $\|x\|_P = \sqrt{x^TPx}$ (for some positive definite matrix $P$) for which $\|x_\gamma'\|_P \leq \|x_0'\|_P$, where $x_0'$ is the least-norm error solution relative to $\|\cdot\|_P$. This could potentially be extended to the case of a non-invertible $B$ using a limit.

Comment: @BenGrossmann unfortunately my problem is concerned with only the $\ell_2$ norm. But I'd still be interested in your $\mathbf{P}$-norm solution to get ideas (I'm not really sure how you'd go about the proof though). Also, for my problem $\mathbf{B}$ isn't invertible but $(\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A} + \gamma\mathbf{B})$ is for sure invertible (just some details that may not be very relevant for the question).

Comment: @johndoe You could use the fact that 
$$
\|x'_\gamma\| \leq c_1 \cdot \|x_\gamma\|_P \leq c_1\cdot \|x_0'\|_P \leq c_1c_2 \cdot \|x_0'\|
$$
for some $c_1,c_2 > 0$. Regarding invertibility, that's exactly why I recommended using a limit

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks again for the pointers, but you've lost me. Can you help a little with the working? My linear algebra is more rusty than I would like it to be :)  
So, for example, do I use $\mathbf{P}:=\mathbf{B}$ or $\mathbf{P}:=(\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{A}+\gamma\mathbf{B})$? And where do $c_1$, $c_2$ come from? Some help would be really appreciated!

Comment: @johndoe See my latest edit. I think that using the specific nature of $G$ would be key to getting any actually useful result here. Are the rows of $G$ orthonormal? That might make things easier

Comment: @BenGrossmann in case you're still interested, you could consider the rows of $\mathbf{G}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ to be a random normal vectors in the null space of $\mathbf{x}^{\ast}$. If you want specifics, I construct it as $\mathbf{G}:=\mathbf{N}\mathbf{K}$ where elements of $\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ are random normal ($k<m$) and the rows of $\mathbf{K}\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$ span the null space of $\mathbf{x}^{\ast}$. Do you still feel that I can use a limit like $\lim_{t\to 0}(\mathbf{B}+t\mathbf{I})$ here? And thanks again!

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think I have a simplification -- since $\mathbf{G}:=\mathbf{N}\mathbf{K}$, therefore $\mathbf{B}:=\mathbf{G}^{\top}\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{K}^{\top}\mathbf{N}^{\top}\mathbf{N}\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{B}=\mathbf{K}^{\top}\mathbf{K}$. We can further assume $\mathbf{K}$ to be orthonormal (which is reasonable for my use-case). Not sure if this makes things easier, but I'll update my question regardless. Just letting you know since you asked about $\mathbf{B}$ being orthonormal.

Answer (score 2):

I will consider only the case where $B$ is invertible. We have
$$
(A^TA + \gamma B)^{-1} A^Ty = \\
B^{-1/2}([AB^{-1/2}]^T[AB^{-1/2}] + \gamma I)^{-1} [AB^{-1/2}]^T y = \\
B^{-1/2}(M^TM + \gamma I)^{-1}M^Ty, \quad M = AB^{-1/2}.
$$
Applying your initial result tells us that
$$
\|(M^TM + \gamma I)^{-1}M^Ty\| \leq \|(M^TM)^{-1}M^Ty\| \implies\\
\|B^{1/2}x_\gamma'\| \leq \|(M^TM)M^Ty\|.
$$
Note that $z = (M^TM)^{-1}M^Ty$ is the minimizing vector $z$ of the minimization $\min_z \|AB^{-1/2}z - y\|$, which means that $x_0 = B^{-1/2}z$  is the minimizing solution to $\min_{x} \|Ax - y\|$. So, $z = B^{1/2}x_0$ and we have
$$
\|B^{1/2} x_\gamma'\| \leq \|B^{1/2}x_0\|.
$$

Note that the norm $\|\cdot\|_B$ defined by $\|x\|_B = \sqrt{x^TBx}$ defines a norm for which $\|x\|_B = \|B^{1/2}x\|$. With that, the above becomes
$$
\|x_\gamma'\|_B \leq \|x_0\|_B.
$$
Now, by the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, we have
$$
c_1^{-2}:= \lambda_{\min}(B) \leq \frac{\|x\|_B^2}{\|x\|^2} = \frac{x^TBx}{x^Tx} \leq \lambda_{\max}(B) =: c_2 \implies\\
c_1^{-2}\|x\|^2 \leq \|x\|_B^2 \leq c_2^2 \|x\|^2.
$$
Note that setting $c_1$ such that $c_1^{-2} = \lambda_{\min}(B)$ only makes sense if the smallest eigenvalue of $B$ is non-zero, which is to say that $B$ is an *invertible* positive definite matrix.

From there, we can conclude that
$$
\|x_\gamma\| \leq c_1 \|x_\gamma\|_B \leq 
c_1 \|x_0\|_B 
\leq c_1 c_2 \|x\| = \sqrt{\kappa(B)}\|x\|,
$$
where $\kappa(B)$ denotes the condition number.

Comment: many, many thanks for this!

Comment: Unfortunately, that $\sqrt{\kappa(\mathbf{B})}$ makes this result not very useful for me. Nonetheless, thanks for the very interesting exercise!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the alternative problem.

Since rows of $\mathbf{K}\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$ are orthonormal, therefore $\mathbf{K}^{\top}\mathbf{K}=\text{diag}(\mathbf{v})$ where $\mathbf{v}=[v_1, \dots, v_m]^{\top}$ and $v_i\in\{0, 1\}$. $\mathbf{v}$ has exactly $k$ ones and $m-k$ zeros.

We can now use the spectral theorem, [as shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145531/regularized-least-squares-solution-norm-bounded-by-least-squares-solution-norm), to show that $\|\mathbf{x}''_{\gamma}\|_2\leq \|\mathbf{x}''_0\|_2$.

---

Edit: Nevermind, this solution is not correct since $v_i\notin \{0, 1\}$ as shown by the counter example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222081/the-columns-of-semi-orthogonal-matrix) (rather, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{K}^{\top}\mathbf{K}$ should be in $\{0, 1\}$). Additionally, $\mathbf{K}^{\top}\mathbf{K}$ is not necessarily a diagonal matrix.