# Eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of matrix sums

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, covariance, positive-definite, matrix-norms

Consider the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G}}:=(\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G})^{\top}(\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G})$ where the rows of $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{G}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ are independently sampled Gaussian random vectors with zero mean (and $\mathbf{X}$ is full-rank, but $\mathbf{G}$ may not be). Now, I want to show that
$$
\| \mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G}}^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\|_2 \leq \| \mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}}^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\|_2\;.
$$
So basically, the term of the left hand side is bounded by the norm of the OLS solution ($\gamma=0$) on the right hand side.

A relevant previous question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582654/replacing-i-with-s-p-d-b-in-ridge-regression-is-the-norm-still-bounded-by).

Here is what I think about this. Since the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G}}$ are for sure larger than the respective eigenvalues of $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}}$ (because variance is additive, and [this holds more generally as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622747/are-the-eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-two-positive-definite-matrices-increased)), therefore eigenvalues of $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G}}^{-1}$ are lower than the respective eigenvalues of $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}}^{-1}$. We can then use the spectral theorem to say that $\| \mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G}}^{-1}\mathbf{z}\|_2 = \sum_i{c_{i,\gamma}(\mathbf{z})^2\lambda_{i, \gamma}^{-2}}$ where $\lambda_{i, \gamma} \geq \lambda_{i, 0}$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G}}$ and $c_{i, \gamma}(\mathbf{z}):=\mathbf{q_{i, \gamma}}^{\top}\mathbf{z}$ where $\mathbf{q_{i, \gamma}}$ are the orthonormal eigenvectors of $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{X}+\gamma\mathbf{G}}$. What I can't figure out is what is the relationship between $\mathbf{q_{i, \gamma}}$ and $\mathbf{q_{i, 0}}$ (which might help with showing the inequality).

Nevertheless, any other approach that might be able to show that the inequality holds would be helpful!